# Inserting calculated element to list of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, insert

This is in python 3.x:

I have one list of lists

```
[['name1', 1, 2, 3] ['name2', 4, 5, 6] ['name3', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Above is just a representation of the type of list of lists I have.

I have tried making a small program with only the same type of problem, so I've eliminated the chance that theres a space or anything in it.

Now I've been trying to insert one calculated integer to the end of each list inside the big list.

```
for i in range(0,1):
     listoflists.insert([i][3],((products/listoflists[i][1])*100))
```

I keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range".

I've tried switching around the indices in the code and I doubt it has anything to do with the index. It's probably something wrong with my code.

I've tried a "for" and "while" loop instead and that doesn't work either. I'm not trying to do this with "i in range(0,1)" specifically, the end result with probably be with len(products).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i][3]
```

This is trying to access the element at index 3 of the list `[i]`, which is what causes the error. You might want to try

```
listoflists[i].insert(3, ...)
```

or just

```
listoflists[i].append(...)
```

to add an item directly to the end of the inner lists.

Comment: Note that: `listoflists[i].insert(3, ...)` will be incorrect for "at the end"... Either 4, or as already mentioned - the much nicer `.append()` method